# Integrate over a polygon in R and take earth's curvature into account

Tags: r, polygon, integral

Starting from a shapefile that gives me districts in terms of (non-convex) polygons (potentially with holes), if I were only interested in their area, I'd have the choice between treating the polygons as planar and using [`rgeos::gArea`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/rgeos/docs/gArea) (which cares about orientation btw) or (better!) taking earth's curvature into account and going with [`geosphere::areaPolygon()`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/geosphere/docs/areaPolygon) (which does not care about orientation and gives me an answer in proper units).

Now, instead of the constant 1-function (which gives me the area), I'd like to integrate a more complicated function. There is e.g. [`polyCub::polyCub.midpoint`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/polyCub/docs/polyCub.midpoint) for the planar case. Is there also something that takes curvature into account?

Some thoughts:

- It should suffice to be able to integrate over a triangle (and thus in particular something convex without holes); one could then use [`rgl::triangulate`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/rgl/docs/triangulate) (or even better since the former gives me segfaults [`RTriangle::triangulate`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/RTriangle/docs/triangulate)) to cut a polygon into triangles.
- I was considering Monte-Carlo sampling. One would then need to be able to get a uniform distribution on the curved polygon. The function [`geosphere::randomCoordinates`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/geosphere/docs/randomCoordinates) goes in that direction, except that (1) it assumes a spherical earth and (2) one would need to be able to restrict the output at least to a bounding rectangle of the polygon upfront since otherwise one has to discard far too many points. There are thoughts on how to carry out uniform sampling on an ellipsoid [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77131/finding-uniformly-distributed-random-points-on-an-ellipsoid) but I find the mathematica code very hard to understand.

*Update*: I've rolled my own solution now. Steps: 1. Triangulate using `RTriangle::triangulate`. 2. evaluate the function at each centroid computed via `geosphere::centroid` (simple Gauss quadrature). 3. Multiply with the area computed via `geosphere::areaPolygon`. 4. Sum it all up.